# SharePoint SPWeb rename - Exception SPException - The security validation for this page is invalid

Tags: development, security

When attempting an SPWeb rename I receive the following SPException:

```
Exception SPException - The security validation for this page is invalid.  Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again. - Failed to create workgroup registration entry
```

Any idea what might be the troubles here?  Here is the relevant code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
         {
             using (SPWeb thisWeb = site.OpenWeb(webUrl))
             {  
                 thisWeb.Title = newName;
                 thisWeb.Update();
             }
          });
```

Comment: a bit off-topic, but just wanted to let you know that it is important that you reinstantiate you SPSite object within a RunWithElevatedPrivileges block to ensure your objects are 100% elevated

Answer (score 4):

First, don't elevate, impersonate!

Second, you need to have SharePoint validate the security digest before changing the context:

```
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();

  SPUserToken sysToken = SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;

  if (sysToken == null)
  {
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
      delegate()
      {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
        {
          sysToken = site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
        }
      }
    );

  }

  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl, sysToken))
  {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
      thisWeb.Title = newName;
      thisWeb.Update(); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for ValidateFormDigest.

Comment: Why Impersonation over Elevation?

Comment: @Jaap: There's info on that here - http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/18/runwithelevatedprivileges-usage-recommendations

Answer (score 1):

Or do elevate and set AllowUnsafeUpdates = true on your web

Comment: I haven't found that to always work. ValidateFormDigest seems more reliable.

Comment: Really? I've never had any problems using it